# Gmail add-on - Access denied: Missing access token

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am learning how to create a Gmail add-on using [this "Quickstart" tutorial / guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart).

Having followed it through and deployed it, I get a run-time error when selecting any thread which has recent threads from the same sender:

```
Error with the add-on.
Run time error.
Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.GetThread. [line: 55, function: , file: Code]
```

I've tried on both my personal and Gsuite accounts, and get the same error.

The code for getting and setting the accessToken is as it should be, according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#setCurrentMessageAccessToken(String)). And the Oauth Scopes are correct as well.

Anyone got any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the minimal example code *in your question*. Currently you are soliciting opinions on why this will might occur.

Comment: Just to make sure this is not a scope-related problem, can you change your scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose" and re-authorize (for new scope to take effect) ?